# Random image filename on my iPhone XS

Tags: iphone, photos

I am wondering why I have randomly named photos on my phone when I copy them to my computer.

Usually the images are all name IMG_0000 etc. and I understand that if there's something like IMG_E0000 then I know that image was edited. But then I'd also have a random single image with AJUQ, CDHF, DQAC, GESE as start intead of IMG. Is there a reason to this?

It kind of throws me off when I look at my pictures as they are just totally out of order.

[image: example here]

Comment: Did you edit these pictures? Or did you take them with a different app?